# Using Node Inspector with multiple node processes

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I started using Node Inspector to debug some of my Node applications. However, one thing i am not sure how to do is, once Node-inspector is attached to one Node app, how to detach and attach it to another Node app running on same box?

How can I debug multiple processes at the same time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Update:*
If you are reading this in 2019, the below answer is out of date. You'd probably want to check out the current documentation or follow gtzilla answer:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

First, start your node programs with different debug ports like so:

```
$ node script1.js --debug==5858
$ node script2.js --debug==5859
```

Then start `node-inspector`

```
$ node-inspector &
```

and open the web console in two tabs with

1. `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858`
2. `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5859`

Comment: why the heck is it == and where in any node docs does it say that ( not that it does not say that, I just want to kno where I bloody missed that lesson )

Answer (score 8):

As mentionned https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911247/1301197 you can specify a port with

```
node --inspect=7000 --inspect-brk app1.js
```

Then of course you just to specify a different port for each node server

```
node --inspect=7001 --inspect-brk app2.js
```

Answer (score 3):

### Attach the debugger

Either by port or by process id. For ports, use a different port for each process. On the command line:

```
node --inspect 8085 some_script_1.js
node --inspect 8086 some_script_2.js
node --inspect 9012 some_script_3.js
```

In a separate terminal window, you can attach to any of these processes with `node inspect <host>:<port>`. For example to attach to `some_script_2.js` on port `8086`

```
node inspect 127.0.0.1:8086
```

Attaching to different processes is matter of changing the port, for example `9012` you would run

```
node inspect 127.0.0.1:9012
```

If you didn't start node on a separate, known port, you can also use the `-p` flag to attach directly to an existing process

```
node inspect -p <node_script_process_id>
```

On Linux and Mac OS use `ps -A | grep node` to find node process ids. Once a process is started, you can also attach the inspector by sending signal to the node process `SIGUSR1` [Reference](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/)

The `node-inspect` program ([source](https://github.com/nodejs/node-inspect)) is separate from core node. Though it is bundled with nodejs. Node inspect reimplements node debug to address a limitation

> For Chrome inspector protocol, there's only one: node --inspect  ... This project tries to provide the missing second option by re-implementing node debug against the new protocol.

[Debugger API documenation](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)

### Additional Ways to Attach Debugger

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

You can view an interact with the debugger in Chrome. Just add additional connections under the `Connections` tab of the dedicated NodeJS DevTools window.

[image: Chrome Window for DevTools connections]

#### Similar, but Separate, Projects

Worth noting there is a similar project, now deprecated, that is called [`node-inspector`](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), which is separate from [`node-inspect`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-inspect) Tested October, 2018 with node v10.11.0

Answer (score 2):

If you use **Chrome**, then you can also use **devtools** directly with url like:

```
devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/0cc79945-8386-4082-aabb-328341bfc953
```

*where `9229/0cc79945-8386-4082-aabb-328341bfc953` - part can be taken from node's output

---

For example, run **first app** with:

```
$ node --inspect-brk=7777 app.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:7777/2df21a01-44ff-40c4-b6ff-1f839f81f9d6
```

and so the result url will be:

```
devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:7777/2df21a01-44ff-40c4-b6ff-1f839f81f9d6
```

then run **second app** instance with:

```
$ node --inspect-brk=7778 app.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:7778/d4e8d8ce-abe9-46c6-89b1-ad0616bdf237
```

and open it with:

```
devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:7778/d4e8d8ce-abe9-46c6-89b1-ad0616bdf237
```