# How to change node.js debug port?

Tags: node.js, debugging

How to change it from 5858 to 7000, for example?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use `--debug` option:

```
node --debug=7000 app.js
```

You can use `--inspect` option for latest node >= v8

```
node --inspect=7000 app.js
```

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/

Comment: This is really useful when having Grunt run multiple concurrent tasks and still have them all debug simultaneously.

Comment: The same syntax applies to nodemon as it passes the param through to node.

Answer (score 8):

For nodejs version >= v8 use this:

```
node --inspect=7000 --inspect-brk app.js
```

Comment: I believe this was the case at least as far back as node v6. (But not v4.)