# node-debugger not start properly in atom editor?

Tags: node.js

when start node-debugger. The Debugger not listening on my port

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DELog.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The port is already in use. Try to use another port or close the other terminal / process which uses the same port.

Comment: Thanks for response me.

I know i use same port but how to start "node-debugger" and nodejs server at same time?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910452/how-to-change-node-js-debug-port) post can help you