# How can I change the default debugger port number in node?

Tags: node.js

I'm facing an error:

```
Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You can do it with ``--debug`` or ``--inspect`` check my answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change node.js debug port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910452/how-to-change-node-js-debug-port)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
node --debug=5412 app.js
```

You can also use `--inspect` option for node version >= v8

```
node --inspect=5622 app.js
```

See for [More Help.](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/)

Comment: thank you! this help. the 9229 port really causes alot of issue

Answer (score 2):

use param "--inspect"

node --inspect=0.0.0.0:[your port] app.js