# VS Code: Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use

Tags: strapi

So far, I have used "processId": {command: PickProcess} ", maybe it's not the best method, but it always worked." Unfortunately, this method has not worked for a few days. (Please see attachment)

In the console I get "Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use".

I have not figured out what the problem is. Can someone give me a hint?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem today. It's never happened before to me.

Comment: I have reinstalled my VS code and synced the settings with another PC. It works again :), but I still do not know what the problem was :(.

Answer (score 21):

I was facing the same issue on my linux machine.

Ran `lsof -i :9229` command to find which process is using port `9229`

Then ran `kill -9 <process id using  the port>`
Its usually extension manager, then restart

Alternatively, you can open process manager in vs code and kill extension host
[image]

Then restart vscode and try to debug by using `attach to process id`

Comment: two commands work for me, thanks.: lsof -i :9229 |  kill -9 <pID>

Answer (score 3):

For windows:

```
C:\Users\Niroshan>netstat -ano|findstr "PID :8080"

Proto Local Address Foreign Address State PID
TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 18264

taskkill /pid 18264 /f
```

as mentioned in [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux)

Comment: I ran `npx kill-port 9229` and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to kill the process and use a different port, you can use the following syntax:

```
node --inspect=7000 app.js
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911247/6908282

Answer (score -1):

It's easy now. You can open the PORTS tab in the same way as you open the terminal in Visual Studio Code, and you can kill the process. This works even in WSL2:

[image: use the PORTS tab in vscode bottom tools]