# Starting inspector on localhost:9229 failed: address already in use

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, port

I'm running a node server using "http.createServer", running on port 3001, when I serve the server the first time it runs, and when I do a small change no matter what I get an error said :

```
**Starting inspector on localhost:9229 failed: address already in use
Server started on http://localhost:3001
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3001
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1372:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1508:7)**
```

about the 9229 - tried to investigate it by running

```
lsof -i :9229
```

and saw that there is 2 instances of it :

```
node    88370    33u  IPv6 0x****************      0t0  TCP localhost:9229 (LISTEN)
node    88370    34u  IPv4 0x****************      0t0  TCP localhost:9229 (LISTEN)
```

when I killed it, it created again and again on each code change, this is the first issue.
the second is regarding: "address already in use :::3001.." what is wrong here? I'm listening to that port -

```
server.listen(3001);
```

do you have any ideas where to investigate it maybe?
thanks!

about the second issue i tried to change ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the port you want the inspector to use with the following syntax:

```
node --inspect=7000 app.js
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911247/6908282